# the title of my blog post color is change depend of monitor

Tags: html, css, templates, colors, blogger

When I change the color of title post to pink, in my computer and tablet it's OK, but my friends told is blue.
I just change color to `#fa2dca`.

```
.page-header1 {
padding: 30px 0 0;
margin: 0;
text-align:center;
}
#column1,#column2,#column3 {float:left}
a{color:#FA2DCA}
```

Pink color in my PC:

[image: Pink color in my PC]

Blue color in the mobile of my friend:

[image: Blue color in the mobile of my friend]

I ask to diferents friends and the same, for some people is blue to anothers is pink. Diferent devices and S.O but everyone use chrome

Comment: Sounds like it's either a media query overwriting the style or the default style of the link is showing (Default colour of an un-styled link is blue). Can you provide an example or a link to the current development?

Comment: http://naaosefaznada.blogspot.co.uk/